# Duplicate each character in a string

Tags: python, string, iteration

I'm looking for a way to duplicate each character in a string, preserving their order. This is the sort of format I need:

```
>>> dup = "abc"
>>> dup1 = MyFunction(dup)  # I don't know what code should go here!
>>> dup1
"aabbcc"
```

I know how to do this for elements in a list, but I can't figure out how to make strings work the same way. What code can I use to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

```
>>> dup = "abc"
>>> dup1 = str()  # a new, empty string.
>>> for char in dup:
...    dup1 += char + char  # strings concatenate using + and +=

>>> dup1  # the duplicant string
'aabbcc'
>>> dup  # the original is preserved
'abc'
```

You can use `dup1 += char` twice in a row instead of `dup1 += char + char` in the `for` block, if you prefer it, or possibly if you want to modify the string between duplication.

`dup1 = ""` may be a more Pythonic alternative to `dup1 = str()`, but I'm not sure. Probably more a matter of style. In either case, an empty string is created.

Comment: If you wanted to do it in a single line, you could use `''.join()` as fredtantini suggested, using an iterator instead:
`dup1 = ''.join(char + char for char in dup)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your code for the lists with strings with:

```
dup1=''.join(yourDuplicateFunction(list(dup)))
```

It will transform the string in list, you will apply your duplicate function on this list, and join it with no separator.